# What is the meaning of these relations?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{dy^2}{dx},\ \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d \ln y}{dx}$$

How am I supposed to use these relations to integrate a function?

Comment: You should post the function that you have to integrate.

Comment: Are they not just general relations?

Comment: these formulas are derivatives.

Comment: Yes, how can I use them to integrate a function?

Comment: Depends on what function you have to integrate. Post the function you  will get more help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that these relations are true because they are just various forms of the chain rule.

These are expressing the left side as the derivative of something with respect to $x$:

$$y \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac12 y^2\right)$$
so, integrating (i.e., applying $\int \ldots \; dx$ to both sides):
$$\int \left(y \frac{dy}{dx}\right)\;dx=\int \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac12 y^2\right)\; dx= \frac12 y^2 + C$$

Likewise for the second one:

$$\frac1y \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left( \ln y\right)$$
so, integrating,
$$\int \left(\frac1y \frac{dy}{dx}\right)\; dx = \int \frac{d}{dx}\left( \ln y\right) \; dx= \ln y + C$$

---

The idea is that if you can write an expression as
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left( \textrm{something}\right)$$
then you know that you can integrate it as
$$\int \frac{d}{dx}\left( \textrm{something}\right)\; dx = (\textrm{something}) + C$$